Is supabase edge functions server location is same as database location?
I fetch data by using supabase edge functions.
final uri = ""https://databasename.supabase.co/functions/v1/~~~;

String requestBodyJson = jsonEncode(requestBody);

      final response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(uri),
        body: requestBodyJson,
        headers: headers,
      );

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));

        final diary = data["data"];
        // prefs 저장
        final jsonList = jsonEncode(diary);
        await prefs.setString(uriKey, jsonList);
        return diary;
      }

But even if it is query to fetch recent 4 data from table, it takes 7-8 seconds.
My supabase database is located in Northeast Asia.

And when I write javascript code for edge functions with new Date().

function getThisWeekStartAndEnd() {
  const now = new Date();
  const koreaDate = now.toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "Asia/Seoul" });
  const currentDate = new Date(koreaDate);

  const currentDayOfWeek = currentDate.getDay();
  const daysUntilMonday = currentDayOfWeek == 0 ? 6 : currentDayOfWeek - 1;

  const monday = new Date(currentDate);
  monday.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - daysUntilMonday);
  monday.setHours(0, 0, 0);

  const sunday = new Date(monday);
  sunday.setDate(monday.getDate() + 6);
  sunday.setHours(23, 59, 59);

  const offset = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 9;
  const mondayInSeconds = Math.floor((monday.getTime() - offset) / 1000);
  const sundayInSeconds = Math.floor((sunday.getTime() - offset) / 1000);

  return { monday: mondayInSeconds, sunday: sundayInSeconds };
}

It prints not korea's timezone, but probably UTC(?) default time.
So I needed to set offset for this.
According to these data, I guess Edge functions server is located not in Northeast Asia, so when I fetch data as using edge functions, it takes longer.
Is it right?
Or is there any way to improve speed for fetching data?
